# The correct way of initialising Google api client on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-api-ruby-client

I have started with [this example](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client-samples/blob/master/calendar/calendar.rb), I managed to make everything work on sinatra.

But I want to use this in my Rails app so I did the followings:

1. Create the client, in sinatra they do that in the configure block.

In rails I did:
   In the `config/initializers` file I've added the entire block which is in sinatra after that I wrote a class `GoogleCalendar::Base` where I have:

```
class GoogleCalendar::Base
  class << self
    attr_accessor :api_client, :calendar_api
  end
  def self.configure
    yield self if block_given?
  end
```

So like this I replaced the `set :api_client, client, set :calendar, calendar`

In my application controller then I've added the:

```
def user_credentials
  ...
  (what i've changed was instead of session i've added `see below`)
  auth.update_token!(access_token: session[:access_token], 
                     refresh_token: session[:refresh_token])
end
```

Because I wasn't working if passing `session` maybe someone can tell me why? (conflict between sessions? and it was working with cookies.)

Also I have created other functions in the application controller which I use for callback and get content.

```
def api_client
  GoogleCalendar::Base.api_client
end

def calendar
  GoogleCalendar::Base.calendar_api
end
```

In the end I've created the rest of the controllers/views and everything works fine.

My final question is: It is ok creating the `Google::APIClient` in the `initialisers` folder because I've notice that every time I change something in my controllers the code brakes, but if I restart the server everything works ok.